# How to remove/replace OneLogin cookies from browser programmatically

Tags: api, authentication, session, token, onelogin

When I Login OneLogin with one user on the same system. it's working fine. but I will Login with another user on the same system, it shows me an error message due to the old user cookie saved on that system.

The below code is used to set OneLogin cookies.

```
function makeCors(session_token,link) { 
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        xhr.withCredentials = true;  
        var url = "https:domain_name_here.onelogin.com/session_via_api_token"; 
        xhr.open("POST", url, true); 
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify({"session_token": session_token})); 
    };
```

Is there any way I can replace or remove OneLogin old user cookie from the browser programmatically?

To give the context we integrated the OneLogin with our React js application.